# Multithreading Crash using QT and QOGL

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, debugging, opencv

I have an QOGLWidget widget which is constructed in a another window, which is activated by button from the QMainwindow. 
I'm trying to send a surface of an image from the widget to the main window's QOGLWidget, the problem that it crashes and gives a first chance exception access violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things that I think may be going on in this situation:

### Qt::AutoConnection

Your connection between your frame generator and the GUI (SimulatorWindow + GLSimulatorWidget)  are connected by [Qt::AutoConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) and ends up turning into a [Qt::DirectConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) when they reside on separate threads.  Specify a connection of [Qt::QueuedConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) to overcome this problem (if indeed they are on separate threads).

### QPixmap v. QImage

You could be handling [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qpixmap.html)s off of the GUI thread.  This usually will print out a warning, but maybe still function.  In general if your processing an image not in the GUI thread, and then sending it to the GUI thread, you need to use something besides [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qpixmap.html), like [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qimage.html).

### Initialization on the Stack

Your frame object may be going out of scope by the time it gets to your GUI.  For example, if you build a frame, and store it in a local scope on the stack, and you pass it into a handler or a container...

...then when you leave the local scope to representing the object in the GUI, your frame object will be gone and your handler/container is left holding a bad pointer.

To fix this, initialize onto the heap and stick to the [Qt Object Model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/object.html).  Also I like to make my containers on the heap also as member variables to the class they belong to.

So in summary:
Check your connection types and if your frame generator is on the GUI thread or not, use QImage not QPixmap if you are in a thread that is not the GUI, and make sure your pointers are not going out of scope.