# Best way in Qt to send OpenGL images between two widgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to use a GLWidget which is inside a simulator window, and would like to send the data using framebuffer object to the mainwindow's glwidget.

I have used signal/slot to achieve that but I had many problems with multi-threading problem and exceptions.

What is the best way to achieve that scenario. ![attached a picture of the scenario I want to do][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share the framebuffer object, you should use GL context resource sharing and not Signal/Slot. The latter runs in main memory, while the context sharing happens on the GPU. So there is no copy of data (transfer over the bus and back!) involved.

In the QGLWidget documentation it is explained how two widgets can have sharing context:

> If shareWidget is a valid QGLWidget, this widget will share OpenGL
>   display lists and texture objects with shareWidget. But if shareWidget
>   and this widget have different formats, sharing might not be possible.
>   You can check whether sharing is in effect by calling isSharing().

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget

Comment: This can leads to crashes due to multithreading?
I have done the signal slot scenario, and I have problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593461/multithreading-crash-using-qt-and-qogl

Comment: The link you posted has nothing to do with the method that I described. In my method, you would at most use signal/slot to trigger the other window to fetch the texture/fbo. The fbo itself stays in the shared context ressources and is not transferred.

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing at hands.